# ThreadPoolExecutor: Not executing in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I did follow the other SO threads but I am not able to figure this out.

```
max_thread = 40
def main():
    variable_name = 1
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_thread) as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(5):
            if count < max_count:
                futures.append(executor.submit(thread_function, xx, yy, zz))
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
        print("Main done with it")
```

Comment: Please show relevant data. This isn't runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a small mistake . lol
reduced indent for this section.

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    future.result()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be absolutely sure what you mean. This is **not** an answer